# Adding shake gesture to GameCenter

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on code which notifies a another user to do something when he shakes his iOS device.
Shakle gesture is working fine but how to integrate that with game centre. I want to to use game centre because it makes very easy to add  friends and invite them but it is basis on clicking on the button. I want to implement same functionality using shake gesture.So instead of clicking on particular user he would shake his device and then next user ould be automatically notified to join him. can I do that.
is it possible to edit funcntionalities of game cente.